# How to reduce query execution time vb.net webform

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

Hi i have this query in my asp.net web form in vb.net with 3,500 data only on the Database but when executing it it takes 10 seconds i suspect it is on the query 
this is the query;

```
/* Formatted on 11/12/2019 2:37:37 PM (QP5 v5.318) */
  SELECT C01.CAR_NO,
         C01.REFNO,
         NVL ((SELECT DEPT_DESC
                 FROM EMP_DEPT
                WHERE DEPTCODE = C01.DEPTID),
              ' ')
             AS DEPTID,
         C01.ERR_PROOF,
         NVL ((SELECT SECTIONNAME
                 FROM IQA_SECTION
                WHERE SECTIONID = AREAID),
              ' ')
             AS AREAID,
         DECODE (AUDITDATE,
                 NULL, 'N',
                 AUDITDATE, TO_CHAR (AUDITDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
             AUDITDATE,
         ISSUEDTO
             AS ISSUEDTOID,
         NVL ((SELECT NAME
                 FROM TQM_VWEMPLOYEE
                WHERE EMP_NUMBER = ISSUEDTO),
              NVL (ISSUEDTO, ' '))
             AS ISSUEDTO,
         DECODE (ISSUEDDATE,
                 NULL, 'N',
                 ISSUEDDATE, TO_CHAR (ISSUEDDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
             ISSUEDDATE,
         DECODE (CLOSEDDATE,
                 NULL, 'N',
                 CLOSEDDATE, TO_CHAR (CLOSEDDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
             CLOSEDDATE,
         CONFORMITY,
         RFI,
         FID,
         NVL ((SELECT NAME
                 FROM TQM_VWEMPLOYEE
                WHERE EMP_NUMBER = AGUIDEID),
              NVL (AGUIDEID, ' '))
             AS AGUIDEID,
         NVL ((SELECT NAME
                 FROM TQM_VWEMPLOYEE
                WHERE EMP_NUMBER = QMID),
              ' ')
             AS QMID,
         NVL ((SELECT NAME
                 FROM TQM_VWEMPLOYEE
                WHERE EMP_NUMBER = AUDITORID),
              ' ')
             AS AUDITORID,
         NVL ((SELECT NAME
                 FROM TQM_VWEMPLOYEE
                WHERE EMP_NUMBER = LOTHEADID),
              NVL (LOTHEADID, ' '))
             AS LOTHEADID,
         NVL ((SELECT NAME
                 FROM TQM_VWEMPLOYEE
                WHERE EMP_NUMBER = ELOTHEADID),
              ' ')
             AS ELOTHEADID,
         NVL ((SELECT NAME
                 FROM TQM_VWEMPLOYEE
                WHERE EMP_NUMBER = VERIFIERID),
              NVL (VERIFIERID, ''))
             AS VERIFIERID,
         NVL ((SELECT NAME
                 FROM TQM_VWEMPLOYEE
                WHERE EMP_NUMBER = EBFG),
              ' ')
             AS EBFG,
         DECODE (TARGET_DATE,
                 NULL, 'N',
                 TARGET_DATE, TO_CHAR (TARGET_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
             TARGET_DATE,
         NVL (CAR_VERIFICATION1, ' ')
             CAR_VERIFICATION1,
         NVL (CAR_VERIFICATION2, ' ')
             CAR_VERIFICATION2,
         DECODE (CAR_D1_RECOMMITDATE,
                 NULL, 'N',
                 CAR_D1_RECOMMITDATE, CAR_D1_RECOMMITDATE)
             CAR_D1_RECOMMITDATE,
         DECODE (CAR_D2_RECOMMITDATE,
                 NULL, 'N',
                 CAR_D2_RECOMMITDATE, CAR_D2_RECOMMITDATE)
             CAR_D2_RECOMMITDATE,
         NVL (FINDINGSDESC, ' ')
             FINDINGSDESC,
         NVL (BFGSECTION, ' ')
             BFGSECTION,
         NVL (AREASECTION, ' ')
             AREASECTION,
         DECODE (NCA_DATE,  NULL, 'N',  NCA_DATE, NCA_DATE)
             NCA_DATE,
         DECODE (NCQ_DATE,  NULL, 'N',  NCQ_DATE, NCQ_DATE)
             NCQ_DATE,
         DECODE (PRL_DATE,  NULL, 'N',  PRL_DATE, PRL_DATE)
             PRL_DATE,
         DECODE (PRAO_DATE,  NULL, 'N',  PRAO_DATE, PRAO_DATE)
             PRAO_DATE,
         DECODE (PRQ_DATE,  NULL, 'N',  PRQ_DATE, PRQ_DATE)
             PRQ_DATE,
         DECODE (VCA_DATE,  NULL, 'N',  VCA_DATE, VCA_DATE)
             VCA_DATE,
         DECODE (VER_DATE,  NULL, 'N',  VER_DATE, VER_DATE)
             VER_DATE,
         NCA_TAG,
         NCQ_TAG,
         PRL_TAG,
         PRAO_TAG,
         PRQ_TAG,
         PRA_TAG,
         VCAF_TAG,
         VER_TAG,
         NVL ((SELECT NAME
                 FROM TQM_VWEMPLOYEE
                WHERE EMP_NUMBER = AOWNERID),
              NVL (AOWNERID, ' '))
             AS AOWNERID,
         AOWNERID
             AS OWNERID,
         NVL (POINTS, ' ')
             POINTS,
         NVL (INTERIM, ' ')
             INTERIM,
         NVL (RCA, ' ')
             RCA,
         NVL (CORRECTIVE, ' ')
             CORRECTIVE,
         SHOW_TAG,
         NVL(TempApprover.CURRENT_APPROVER, ' ')
             CURRENT_APPROVER,
         NVL (REMARKS, ' ')
             REMARKS
    FROM IQA_CAR C01,
         (SELECT C02.CAR_NO,
                 DECODE (A01.APP_DESC,
                         'AUDITORID', (SELECT NAME
                                         FROM TQM_VWEMPLOYEE
                                        WHERE EMP_NUMBER = C02.AUDITORID),
                         'QMID', (SELECT NAME
                                    FROM TQM_VWEMPLOYEE
                                   WHERE EMP_NUMBER = C02.QMID),
                         'VERIFIERID', (SELECT NAME
                                          FROM TQM_VWEMPLOYEE
                                         WHERE EMP_NUMBER = C02.VERIFIERID),
                         'LOTHEADID', (SELECT NAME
                                         FROM TQM_VWEMPLOYEE
                                        WHERE EMP_NUMBER = C02.LOTHEADID),
                         'AOWNERID', (SELECT NAME
                                        FROM TQM_VWEMPLOYEE
                                       WHERE EMP_NUMBER = C02.AOWNERID),
                         NULL, 'N')
                     CURRENT_APPROVER
            FROM IQA_CAR C02, IQA_APPROVAL A01, IQA_TRACKER T01
           WHERE C02.CAR_NO = T01.REFNO AND A01.APP_NO = T01.APP_NO)
         TempApprover
   WHERE     TempApprover.CAR_NO(+) = C01.CAR_NO
         AND SHOW_TAG = 1
         AND ab_getaudittypeid (deptid) = 11

ORDER BY C01.CAR_NO DESC
```

i try to optimize the query but nothing changes on the execution time and i uses data reader in my behind code part because they say DataReader works faster

here's my new query

```
SELECT   c01.car_no, c01.refno,
         NVL ((SELECT dept_desc
                 FROM emp_dept
                WHERE deptcode = c01.deptid), ' ') AS deptid, c01.err_proof,
         NVL ((SELECT sectionname
                 FROM iqa_section
                WHERE sectionid = areaid), ' ') AS areaid,
         NVL (TO_CHAR (auditdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'N') AS auditdate,
         issuedto AS issuedtoid,
         NVL ((SELECT NAME
                 FROM tqm_vwemployee
                WHERE emp_number = issuedto),
              NVL (issuedto, ' ')) AS issuedto,
         NVL (TO_CHAR (issueddate, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'N') AS issueddate,
         NVL (TO_CHAR (closeddate, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'N') AS closeddate,
         conformity, rfi, fid,
         NVL ((SELECT NAME
                 FROM tqm_vwemployee
                WHERE emp_number = aguideid),
              NVL (aguideid, ' ')) AS aguideid,
         NVL ((SELECT NAME
                 FROM tqm_vwemployee
                WHERE emp_number = qmid), ' ') AS qmid,
         NVL ((SELECT NAME
                 FROM tqm_vwemployee
                WHERE emp_number = auditorid), ' ') AS auditorid,
         NVL ((SELECT NAME
                 FROM tqm_vwemployee
                WHERE emp_number = lotheadid),
              NVL (lotheadid, ' ')
             ) AS lotheadid,
         NVL ((SELECT NAME
                 FROM tqm_vwemployee
                WHERE emp_number = elotheadid), ' ') AS elotheadid,
         NVL ((SELECT NAME
                 FROM tqm_vwemployee
                WHERE emp_number = verifierid),
              NVL (verifierid, '')
             ) AS verifierid,
         NVL ((SELECT NAME
                 FROM tqm_vwemployee
                WHERE emp_number = ebfg), ' ') AS ebfg,
         NVL (TO_CHAR (target_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'N') AS target_date,
         NVL (car_verification1, ' ') car_verification1,
         NVL (car_verification2, ' ') car_verification2,
         NVL (TO_CHAR (car_d1_recommitdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
              'N'
             ) AS car_d1_recommitdate,
         NVL (TO_CHAR (car_d2_recommitdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
              'N'
             ) AS car_d2_recommitdate,
         NVL (findingsdesc, ' ') findingsdesc,
         NVL (bfgsection, ' ') bfgsection, NVL (areasection, ' ') areasection,
         NVL (TO_CHAR (nca_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'N') AS nca_date,
         NVL (TO_CHAR (ncq_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'N') AS ncq_date,
         NVL (TO_CHAR (prl_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'N') AS prl_date,
         NVL (TO_CHAR (prao_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'N') AS prao_date,
         NVL (TO_CHAR (prq_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'N') AS prq_date,
         NVL (TO_CHAR (vca_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'N') AS vca_date,
         NVL (TO_CHAR (ver_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'N') AS ver_date, nca_tag,
         ncq_tag, prl_tag, prao_tag, prq_tag, pra_tag, vcaf_tag, ver_tag,
         NVL ((SELECT NAME
                 FROM tqm_vwemployee
                WHERE emp_number = aownerid),
              NVL (aownerid, ' ')) AS aownerid, aownerid AS ownerid,
         NVL (points, ' ') points, NVL (interim, ' ') interim,
         NVL (rca, ' ') rca, NVL (corrective, ' ') corrective, show_tag,
         tempapprover.current_approver current_approver,
         NVL (remarks, ' ') remarks
    FROM iqa_car c01,
         (SELECT c02.car_no,
                 DECODE (a01.app_desc,
                         'AUDITORID', (SELECT NAME
                                         FROM tqm_vwemployee
                                        WHERE emp_number = c02.auditorid),
                         'QMID', (SELECT NAME
                                    FROM tqm_vwemployee
                                   WHERE emp_number = c02.qmid),
                         'VERIFIERID', (SELECT NAME
                                          FROM tqm_vwemployee
                                         WHERE emp_number = c02.verifierid),
                         'LOTHEADID', (SELECT NAME
                                         FROM tqm_vwemployee
                                        WHERE emp_number = c02.lotheadid),
                         'AOWNERID', (SELECT NAME
                                        FROM tqm_vwemployee
                                       WHERE emp_number = c02.aownerid),
                         NULL, 'N'
                        ) current_approver
            FROM iqa_car c02, iqa_approval a01, iqa_tracker t01
           WHERE c02.car_no = t01.refno AND a01.app_no = t01.app_no) tempapprover
   WHERE tempapprover.car_no(+) = c01.car_no AND show_tag = 1
         AND ab_getaudittypeid (deptid) = 11
ORDER BY c01.car_no DESC
```

Is there any thing wrong with my query or may someone help me optimize it
Thank you in advance

Comment: You have lots of select sub queries(11) in the main select clause. Try to avoid them by using them in left join in main `from` clause. Also dont use old style joins. Instead use standard ANSI joins.

Comment: sorry i'm new in joining

Comment: thank ypu bro for the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after many hours i able to solve my problem here's my latest query

```
SELECT   iqa_car.car_no, iqa_car.refno, NVL (iqa_car.deptid, ' '),
         NVL (iqa_car.bfgsection, ' '), iqa_car.err_proof,
         NVL (iqa_section.sectionname, ' '), NVL (To_char(iqa_car.auditdate,'YYYY-MM-DD'), ' '),
         NVL (iqa_car.issuedto, ' '), NVL (tqm_vwemployee.NAME, ' '),
         NVL (To_Char(iqa_car.issueddate,'YYYY-MM-DD'), ' '), NVL (To_Char(iqa_car.closeddate,'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'N'),
         NVL (vw_curr_approver.current_approver, ' ')
    FROM iqa_car LEFT OUTER JOIN iqa_section
         ON iqa_section.sectionid = iqa_car.areaid
         LEFT OUTER JOIN tqm_vwemployee
         ON tqm_vwemployee.emp_number = iqa_car.issuedto
         FULL OUTER JOIN vw_curr_approver
         ON vw_curr_approver.car_no = iqa_car.car_no
   WHERE ab_getaudittypeid (deptid) = 11
     AND TO_CHAR (iqa_car.issueddate, 'yyyy') = '2019'
ORDER BY iqa_car.car_no DESC
```

Thanks for @Tejash for the idea

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
WITH V1 AS (
    SELECT c02.car_no,
                 DECODE (a01.app_desc, 'AUDITORID', (SELECT NAME FROM tqm_vwemployee  WHERE emp_number = c02.auditorid),
                                       'QMID', (SELECT NAME FROM tqm_vwemployee  WHERE emp_number = c02.qmid),
                                       'VERIFIERID', (SELECT NAME FROM tqm_vwemployee WHERE emp_number = c02.verifierid),
                                       'LOTHEADID', (SELECT NAME FROM tqm_vwemployee  WHERE emp_number = c02.lotheadid),
                                       'AOWNERID', (SELECT NAME FROM tqm_vwemployee WHERE emp_number = c02.aownerid),
                                       NULL, 'N' ) current_approver
            FROM iqa_car c02 inner join  iqa_approval a01 on c02.car_no = t01.refno 
                             inner join  iqa_tracker t01 on  a01.app_no = t01.app_no
)
SELECT  c01.car_no,
        c01.refno,
        NVL (V1.current_approver, ' ') AS deptid,

        // more here...

FROM iqa_car c01 left join V1 on c01.car_no = V1.car_no AND show_tag = 1 AND ab_getaudittypeid (deptid) = 11;
```

- You can also create new function for `SELECT NAME FROM tqm_vwemployee`, it make your code more readable.